# jQuery deep extend and preserve all properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

After running this bit:

```
var o1 = {
    a: { x: 1, y: 2 }
};
var o2 = {
    a: { z: 3 }
};
var result = $.extend(true, o1, o2);
```

I find that `result` is `{ a: { z: 3 } }`. Is there a way to have it contain the properties of both `o1.a` and `o2.a`?

In other words, is there a way to change the above script so that `result` would be:

```
{
    a: { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }
}
```

?

*Edit: The code was wrong. It actually works as expected after fixing the parameter order.*

Comment: i think you're arguments are out of order for deep copy. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend

Comment: Have you tried `var result = $.extend(true, o1.a, o2.a);` true for deep copy

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the incorrect order of parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `deep` argument goes first. `jQuery.extend( [deep ], target, object1 [, objectN ] )`

```
var o1 = {
    a: { x: 1, y: 2 }
};
var o2 = {
    a: { z: 3 }
};
var result = $.extend(true, o1, o2);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use deep copy, you should pass `true` as FIRST parameter:

```
var result = $.extend(true, o1, o2);
```